# Can you use Document.SetPropertyValue(string,string) on nested properties?

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

Say for a given DocumentDb document such as:

```
{
    "id": "CDC101",
    "title": "Fundamentals of database design",
    "authordetails": { 
       "Name" : "Dave",
       "Age : "33"
    },
    "credits":  10
}
```

If I wanted to update authordetails.Name using SetPropertyValue, what syntax would I use? The following doesn't seem to work as I'd expect it to:

```
//Fetch the Document to be updated
Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collectionLink)
                            .Where(r => r.Id == "CDC101")    
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .SingleOrDefault();

//Update some properties on the found resource
doc.SetPropertyValue("authordetails.Name", "Mike");

//Now persist these changes to the database by replacing the original resource
Document updated = await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(doc);
```

The reason I ask: I have to change a single property on a large number of documents in the collection (new requirement), and I'm trying to process them from a queue on a separate process to avoid the UI timing out. I considered a sproc, but being javascript based, and without a batch upsert like mongo I'm failing to find a suitable & scalable way to do this. I'm new to the NoSQL way of thinking and I'm quite baffled. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This methos worked for me:
You can use GetPropertyValue to read and write a nested property as a dynamic

```
//Fetch the Document to be updated
Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collectionLink)
                            .Where(r => r.Id == "CDC101")    
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .SingleOrDefault();

dynamic AuthInfo = doc.GetPropertyValue<dynamic>("AuthInfo");
AuthInfo.Name = "mike";
doc.SetPropertyValue("AuthInfo", AuthInfo);

//Now persist these changes to the database by replacing the original resource
Document updated = await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(doc);
```

Comment: Some words of explanation usually are appreciated in stack overflow answers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I never wrote before in Stack Overflow and I got some problems  formatting text.

Comment: Explanation: the Azure.Document class has a broken implementation of IDynamicMetadatatProvider (or whatever its called,) so it does not understand how to SetProperty for nested properties. However, you can SetProperty its top-level properties just fine. But, all of its nested properties are Newtonsoft types like JObject, JArray, which have their own, non-broken implementation of the IDynamicMetadataProvider interface. So once you peel off the top-level object (AuthInfo in the example, which is JObject), you can manipulate it then set that object on the root Azure.Document when you're done.

Answer (score 1):

SetPropertyValue does not support to set nested properties. You could submit this user voice at [Azure feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb?query=nest). At currently, we can query the document as an object then replace the document. Refer to below code:

```
var entity = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Cred>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("<databaseid>", "<collectionid>")).Where(r => r.ID == "CDC101")
                        .AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault();
entity.AuthInfo.Name = "mike";
await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("<databaseid>", "<collectionid>", entity.ID), entity);
```

This is my tested class:

```
public class Cred
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "credits")]
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "authordetails")]
    public AuthDetail AuthInfo { get; set; }
}
public class AuthDetail
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

We can also use store produce to do this:

```
// SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample() {
var collection = getContext().getCollection();

// Query documents and take 1st item.
var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
    'SELECT * FROM root r',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) getContext().getResponse().setBody('no docs found');
        else getContext().getResponse().setBody(JSON.stringify(feed[0]));
        var doc= feed[0];
        doc.authordetails.Name="mike";
        var isAccepted = collection.replaceDocument(feed[0]._self, doc);  
    });

if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how would I be able to dynamically update properties by a string path, rather than by code, ie:

ideally:
doc.fields["authordetails.Name"] ="mike";

rather than:
doc.authordetails.Name="mike";

I suspect I'll need to search for the required field.

Comment: As I know, It would be not possible at currently. I would suggest you submit a voice via the link I provide in this answer.